# ExpandablelistView on fragment

Tags: android, fragment, expandable

I'm trying to use a expandablelistView in my code but I have some problems.I'm trying to implement this code in a fragment. Can help me make this code to be used in a fragment ? I need to use it in a fragment.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class TextExpandable extends AppCompatActivity {

    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
    List<String> expandableListTitle;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        expandableListDetail = ExpandableListDataPump.getData();
        expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
        expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(this, expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Expanded.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Collapsed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                                + " -> "
                                + expandableListDetail.get(
                                expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just extend your class with fragment. operation you are doing in onCreate() do the same as oncreateView() of fragement.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.aksu.R;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {


    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
    List<String> expandableListTitle;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;
    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return init(inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false));
    }

    private View init(View inflate) {
        expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) inflate.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        expandableListDetail = ExpandableListDataPump.getData();
        expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
        expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(inflate., expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
        expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(inflate.,
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Expanded.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                Toast.makeText(inflate.,
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Collapsed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        inflate.,
                        expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                                + " -> "
                                + expandableListDetail.get(
                                expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                                childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this  : you need to change onCreate to onCreateView and findViewBy Id to rootView.findViewById() and getActivity will get activity for your custom adapter

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class TextExpandable extends Fragment {

ExpandableListView expandableListView;
ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
List<String> expandableListTitle;
HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;
view rootView;


public TextExpandable(){
//default constructor
}
@Override
protected void onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.history_courses,container,false);


    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
    expandableListDetail = ExpandableListDataPump.getData();
    expandableListTitle = new ArrayList<String>(expandableListDetail.keySet());
    expandableListAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), expandableListTitle, expandableListDetail);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Expanded.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition) + " List Collapsed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    getActivity(),
                    expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)
                            + " -> "
                            + expandableListDetail.get(
                            expandableListTitle.get(groupPosition)).get(
                            childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

hope it works.